# Redirecting AT commands to microcom command under Linux

Tags: linux, redirect, pipe, stdin, tty

in the `BusyBox` [command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) for Linux exists the command `microcom` to communicate with a serial modem:

```
BusyBox v1.13.2 (2012-05-10 17:13:08 CEST) multi-call binary

Usage: microcom [-d DELAY] [-t TIMEOUT] [-s SPEED] [-X] TTY

Copy bytes for stdin to TTY and from TTY to stdout

Options:    
        -d  Wait up to DELAY ms for TTY output before sending every next byte to it
        -t  Exit if both stdin and TTY are silent for TIMEOUT ms
        -s  Set serial line to SPEED
        -X  Disable special meaning of NUL and Ctrl-X from stdin
```

Instead of using stdin to type the AT commands I want to place them insise a text file and redirect the content of that file as the stdin for the above command. For example, I have a file

```
/tmp/at.txt
```

with the AT command `AT`, which usually gets confirmed by the TTY with an `OK`. A standard session with stdin looks like:

```
microcom -t 3000 -X /dev/ttyS5                                 
at
OK
```

in which the string `at` was entered directly on the keyboard. In order to use the content of the file `/tmp/at.txt` (contains just 'at\n'). To do this,. I have tried the following variations:

```
microcom -t 3000 -X /dev/ttyS5  < /tmp/at.txt   
microcom -t 3000 /dev/ttyS5  < /tmp/at.txt 
cat /tmp/at.txt |  microcom -t 3000 /dev/ttyS5
tail -f  /tmp/at.txt |  microcom -t 3000 /dev/ttyS5
cat /tmp/at.txt |  microcom -t 3000 /dev/ttyS5 -X
tail -f  /tmp/at.txt |  microcom -t 3000 /dev/ttyS5 -X
```

and none of them worked, i.e. none of those commands did return the text 'OK' on the screen. I therefore conclude that there is some problem redirecting the content of the file `/tmp/at.txt` as stdin for the command `microcom`. Maybe is has to do with how the end-of-line is interpreted or the end-of-file. If someone has some idea, I would appreciate some help.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 10):

You need end **AT COMMANDS** with special character **\r**

```
echo "AT+CIMI\r" | microcom -t 2000 /dev/ttyS5
```

With **\n** it doesn't work

Grettings

Comment: if beside busybox you use a real shell, like bash, don't forget the specifiy the -e and -n flag to echo:  `echo -ne "AT+CSQ\r\n" | microcom -X -t 1000 /dev/modem_at1`

Answer (score 5):

Im running the microcom in BusyBox v1.18.4 under SliTaz 4.0 & I duplicated the problem & then solved it. If youre going to emulate keyboard input at this level the takefile has to have a full CRLF after every line because the keyboard  key transmits a ^M (0x0D). The Linux standard 0x0A written by most ASCII editors is not sufficient.

There are many ways to do it but I just created the takefile with an extra byte at the end of every line then used the ncurses-hexedit program to zap the byte to a 0x0D. I tested the above commands & got an OK response with the input taken from such a file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

echo ATE | sudo socat - /dev/ttys5,crnl